# Populate an NSImageView box from NSString data

Tags: objective-c, image, cocoa

I am very new to Objective C and I've been searching Google for a number of hours trying to find a solution.

I have an NSString which looks like

```
273350/364D4D002A00041EB8F1E0CEF1E0CCF1E0CCF1E0CCF1E0CCF etc etc
```

which refers to a TIFF image (I guess in some sort of RAW string format), I want to populate an NSImageView with the data.

This is what I've attempted so far:

```
NSData *picdata = [NSData dataWithBytes:[albumArtStr UTF8String] length:[albumArtStr length]];
NSImage *myPicture = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:picdata];
[_albumArtCell setImage:myPicture];
```

Where "albumArtCell" is the NSImageView

Comment: so what happend after this?

Comment: The ImageView stayed empty :(. I don't suppose there's a way to even test that `myPicture` is being set correctly!

Comment: i think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343814/drawing-nsstring-to-uiimage) can help you

Comment: I believe that is to superimpose text onto an image rather than create an image from a hex string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data looks like hex encoded image with a length in front of it, not an unencoded TIFF, which is a tagged binary format.   Perhaps you need to strip the number before the slash and decode e rest of the string from hex digits into NSData and then call `[[NSImage alloc] initWithData]` using that decided data.

You will need to decode it to binary before handing it to `NSImage` as it only understands the raw binary form of TIFF.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is due to the fact that `[albumArtStr length]` returns the number of "unicode character", and not number of "bytes".

So your NSData is probably not set-up to be the right size and so doesn't have the right format for a UIImage to be decoded properly.

Try this instead to create a NSData from NSString instance:

```
NSData* picData = [albumArtStr dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```